# NSLog but show the raw unicode string

Tags: cocoa, nslog

For example, it prints below string:

"user_description" = "\U5efa\U5b50\Uff0c\U6b4c\U540e\Uff0c\U5c0f\U5e86\Uff0c\U5c0fKen\Uff0c\U8fd9\U4e9b\U90fd\U662f\U6211\U3002\U6211\U60f3\U505a\U7684\U5c31\U662f\Uff0c\U6253\U5f00\U53cc\U624b\Uff0c\U62e5\U62b1\U4f60\U3002";

any one know how to print the actual string instead these un-readable characters?

or do you know why this issue happen? how to avoid it? encoding?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you print it out, or what type of string it is, but have you played with different types of format specifiers? [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)